# If user inputs letter output should be word

Tags: python, variables, input

Basically, my game runs off 3 words - Steal, Deal or Quit however I want the option that if the user inputs say the letter 's' it should = Steal as the output (The player is versing a PC and the results of the game are based on the 2 values.

```
human = input('Steal, Deal or Quit [s|d|q]?:')

print(" ")

print('You chose: ' + human)

#Computer input
     
sd = ["Steal", "Deal"]
computer_choice = random.choice(sd)

print('Comp chose: ' + computer_choice)

print(" ")

if human == computer_choice:
    print('Draw! Split pot -50 each')
elif human == 'Steal' and computer_choice == 'Deal':
    print('You win! You gain 100.')
elif human == 'Deal' and computer_choice == 'Steal':
    print('You loose! Comp gain 100.')
elif human == 'Steal' and computer_choice == 'Steal':
    print('Too Greedy! You get nothing')
```

Comment: Why is there no code for `quit`?

Comment: Please, in the future, make a [mre]. 90% of your code is irrelevant to the question.

Comment: That's my fault I copied and pasted it twice, it's not an intentional repeat. I am just working through it step by step, the quit code is the next step! Thanks for the minimal reproducible example will be a good help in the future!

Answer (score 2):

You should use a dictionary to map the human letter input to the words `Steal` or `Deal`

First add the dictionary at the top:

```
human_input_map = {
    's': 'Steal'
    'd': 'Deal'
}
```

Then after taking the user input you can convert their input into the full word for comparing with `computer_choice`.

```
human = input('Steal, Deal or Quit [s|d|q]?:')

human = human_input_map[human]
```